# A 206 mH inductor is connected to an AC generator producing an rms voltage of 7 V. If an rms current of 32 mA flows, what is the generator frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity

I don't even know where to start with this question.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236